# A fact about Sun

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I'm here, enjoying a sunset. But isn't it that saying "sunset" is wrong? We all know Earth orbits around Sun, so why do we call "sunset" and "sunrise" if we know *for sure* that the Sun isn't rising/setting at all?

Comment: Worse yet, as you look at the edge of the sun at sunset, you see only an afterimage refracted around the curve of the Earth by the air.  The sun has already gone behind the Earth, and you are not really looking at it.  Is the sun's edge 'on the horizon', or is it really behind the Earth, where the science says it has to be?  We are still free to express things in human terms when we know those are only stories based on approximations or conventions.  Slow down.  Each of your questions here has dozens of amazing parts to it.  Please try to ask just one.

Comment: This reminds me of an exchange I witnessed between a county clerk, and a rustic straight out of the hills, over the absence of a birth certificate needed to complete some government form. The rustic finally said 'maybe I can't prove I was born, but you can't deny I'm here'

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to encourage more of this, but less.  My point was that if the very first sentence calls for all that, there is obviously too much here for anyone to answer.  We try not to be a blog, but a place where separate questions have separate answers that can be compared.  You need to break this up, or it will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

It is people's habit to name beautiful phenomena if it happens more or less frequently.  Sunrise and sunset are two such phenomena. This naming is necessary to indicate (the time of) the presence and absence of the most important source of living things in each day's talk. People might have named these phenomena before the truth about the Sun is revealed. If we apply our science here, we might be compelled to use more words. And they would create inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Fun question!

I suspect it is because our reality is subjective and we name the phenomenon for the way it appears to us.  Because of relativity, from our perspective, the sun does set and it is the sun, not we, which is moving.

This is not *so* inconsistent with what is actually going on, because the rising and setting of the sun is a function of the rotation of the earth in a roughly 24 hour cycle, as distinct from the the revolution of the earth around the sun.  It's more that, from our perspective "the sun sets" below the horizon where we can no longer see it.

As @SonOfThought astutely points out, using scientific language to accurately describe the phenomenon would be more expensive linguistically, less aesthetically pleasing, and unlikely to catch on.  (Even scientists use "sunrise" and "sunset" as shorthand.;)